# Проблема с русским языком в моём android приложении

Tags: android, json

у меня есть функция которая добавляет комент
он работает но когда я добавляю комент на русском он показывает его так `??????`

Как мне это исправить ?

функция

```
public void showCommentDialog(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //you should edit this to fit your needs
        builder.setTitle("Double Edit Text");

        final EditText one = new EditText(this);
        one.setHint("Name");//optional
        final EditText two = new EditText(this);
        two.setHint("Comment");//optional

        //in my example i use TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER for input only numbers
        one.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
        //two.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
        lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lay.addView(one);
        lay.addView(two);
        builder.setView(lay);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //get the two inputs
                String NameC = one.getText().toString();
                String TextC = two.getText().toString();

                AddComment.addCOMENT(id, NameC, TextC);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

адаптер этой функции

```
public class AddComment {
    private static String jsonResult;
    private static String url = "http://dushanbe.96.lt/nek3.php";
    private static String ID, NAME, TEXT;

    public static class JsonReadTast extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public JsonReadTast() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",ID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",NAME));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text",TEXT));

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (Exception e){

            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine())!= null){
                    answer.append(line);
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){

            }

            return answer;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        }
    }

    public static void startWebService(){
        JsonReadTast task = new JsonReadTast();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public static void addCOMENT(String Id, String name, String text){
        ID = Id;
        NAME = name;
        TEXT = text;
        startWebService();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была такая же проблема, как вариант отправлять байты:

POST(`MultiPartEntity`):

```
String name = "Имя"
builder.addBinaryBody("name", name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Или кодировать строку Вам должно подойти:

```
private String encode(String value) {
        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо с четением комента помогло но с добавление таже проблема

Comment: builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //get the two inputs
                 encode(one.getText().toString());
                 encode(two.getText().toString());
                String NameC = one.getText().toString();
                        String TextC =one.getText().toString();
                encode(NameC);
                encode(TextC);
                Name.setText(NameC);
                AddComment.addCOMENT(id, NameC, TextC);
            }
        });

Comment: Отправляйте в обертке:  `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",encode(NAME)));`

Comment: теперь показывает вот так %D0%BC и тагдалее что мне делать ?

Comment: а как вариант использовать `MultiPartEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы уверены, что отправляете коммент на сервер правильно и от его понимает, то проблема в кодировке при чтении ответа. Вот это решение должно помочь.

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, <кодировка ответа сервера>));
```